# Keeping the data based on date in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input DataFrame

```
ID        Data                       Date
 1           A           01-04-2020 23:50
             B            02-04-2020 6:15
 2           C           30-03-2020 22:10
             D           28-03-2020  8:15
 3           E           26-03-2020  7:20
```

Output I want

```
ID        Data                       Date
 1           A           01-04-2020 23:50
 2           D           28-03-2020  8:15
 3           E           26-03-2020  7:20
```

I have tried by sorting the Date

```
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort('Date')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `ID` your index? If not, are the blanks in `ID` missing values ('nan`)?

Comment: what is the logic for dropping the rows?

Comment: @QuangHoang ID are index and the rows having blank ID belongs to the same ID

Comment: @RustyShackleford Basically I want to drop rows having latest dates and keep the rows having earliest dates for each ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to keep the first date:

```
 df.sort_values('Date').groupby('ID').first()
```

Output:

```
   Data                Date
ID                         
1     A 2020-01-04 23:50:00
2     D 2020-03-28 08:15:00
3     E 2020-03-26 07:20:00
```